# How to create data volume in docker?

Tags: docker

I am having some gitcode (around 10gb) kept in a folder "src" in my home directory. I have read somewhere that we can mount this code as a data volume in docker.
I am a newbie to docker. I only have an idea of using "docker volume create" command, but totally unsure about how to use it.

Could someone help me in achieving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bishal's answer has instructions how to use mapping with Docker compose. When using plain docker, use command

```
docker run -v <absolute path to src folder on host>:<absolute path on container> some-image
# Real example:
docker run -v ~/src:/src some-image
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker allows for easy volume mapping. This can be configured in your docker-compose.yaml file.

Volume mapping allows you to share a directory in your host machine to your docker-container.

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

In the above snippet, the files in the current directory of host machine will be mapped to /code of the docker container.

[This article](https://www.linux.com/learn/docker-volumes-and-networks-compose) has detailed explanation.